# HTML - Switch Desktop and Mobile view is not working on browser resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, toggle

I have a web page that allows switching between Mobile/Desktop view. I use the below code to toggle between desktop and Mobile layouts.

```
$('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'); // Toggle code for Mobile View

$('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=1024');  // Toggle code for Desktop View
```

The above works perfectly in chrome device simulator mode.  However, if I disable the device simulator and resize the desktop to Mobile width and try the toggle, it is not working.  But the viewport content property changes as per the toggle code.

**Update:**

1. Responsive design works perfectly in Mobile devices (Say, when width < n Pixels);  The desktop and the Mobile view is switchable using a toggle button using the above-mentioned code.
2. Responsive design works perfectly in Desktop Browser (When width resized to < n Pixels); The Desktop and Mobile view is not switchable.  This is the issue.

Comment: Did you tried with `initial-scale=1.0`? If you use Bootstrap, why you use two different layouts?

Comment: Did you try with .resize(). or try calling the same code within .resize().

Comment: Yes, I am calling the same code in resize().

Answer (score -1):

Try to use bootstrap media query breakpoints
https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.  Use this to do what?

Answer (score -1):

I tried the same code in different bootstrap layouts.  The results are the same.  There seems to be no issue with my code.

```
$('meta[name="viewport"]').prop('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'); // Toggle code for Mobile View
```

This is intended to work on Mobile devices or simulators. Not for desktop browsers.

Switching Mobile/Desktop views in the browser seems not an option.

Refer this answer: [set viewport using meta viewport tag for desktop browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485670/set-viewport-using-meta-viewport-tag-for-desktop-browsers)