# Is it possible to replace the browser's default zooming behaviour with magnification?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building an admin panel for a client using the [Metronic](https://keenthemes.com/metronic) theme. Accessibility is not important to the client and responsiveness is not too important either since this application will only be used on desktops/laptops. Zooming into the application breaks the appearance of some components.

Would it be possible to replace zooming with magnification (the behaviour achieved by pinching and zooming on a laptop trackpad).

To help you visualise what I mean I used StackOverflow as an example;

StackOverflow without zooming/magnification;

[image: website without zooming/magnification]

StackOverflow when zooming in (Ctrl+Shift+Plus);

[image: website when zooming]

StackOverflow when magnifying (Pinch and zoom on a trackpad);

[image: website when magnifying]

I want the third behaviour to happen when zooming regularly also. I have tried adjusting the meta viewport tag but according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485670/set-viewport-using-meta-viewport-tag-for-desktop-browsers) and many others, viewport is only for mobile devices. There is also no zoom event in JavaScript to do try to see if `e.preventDefault` would make it work.

Even if I end up having to make everything responsive anyways it would be interesting to see if this is possible.

Comment: It's not clear what the differences are.

Comment: When magnifying the layout of the page does not move or shift is any way. Pinching and zooming makes the website behave as if you're using the Windows Magnifier on a webpage.

Comment: Updated the question with StackOverflow because the difference is clearer